# How to change the .mobileprovision in xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode5

can we change the .mobileprovision file in xcode. I want to change like this

from this

```
  <dict>
            <key>application-identifier</key>
            <string>ZYR93MSDF.com.text.catalogapp.Coredata</string>
            <key>get-task-allow</key>
            <true/>
            <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
            <array>
                <string>RSTY3GX5ZY.*</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
```

to this

```
<key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>ZYR93MSDF.com.text.catalogapp.Coredata</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <string>ZYR93MSDF.com.text.catalogapp.Coredata</string>
```

but can't do this if i change something in .mobileprovision file it is not installed.
please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't edit provision profile by hand. Go to [Developers portal](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) and edit provision portal there. Then in Xcode go to Preference - Account and refresh profiles

Also you can use [iPhone Configuration Utility 3.5 for Mac OS X](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465)
 tool for managing provision profiles